# How To Match Data Types from Plist To Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Given the following data structure:

```
<dict>
<key>Attachments</key>
<dict>
    <key>__deferred</key>
    <dict>
        <key>uri</key>
            <string>http://myserver/mysite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/OLPerson(2)/Attachments</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>ContentType</key>
<string>OLPerson</string>
<key>ContentTypeID</key>
<string>0x0100EA6E4D97C50CDB4C969ADE34F3DDD6630008BBD0E63B1D0C438CE98422AB07F904</string>
<key>Created</key>
<string>/Date(1358159519000)/</string>
<key>CreatedBy</key>
<dict>
    <key>__deferred</key>
    <dict>
        <key>uri</key>
            <string>http://myserver/mysite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/OLPerson(2)/CreatedBy</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>CreatedById</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>Id</key>
<integer>2</integer>
<key>Modified</key>
<string>/Date(1365691793000)/</string>
<key>ModifiedBy</key>
<dict>
    <key>__deferred</key>
    <dict>
        <key>uri</key>
            <string>http://myserver/mysite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/OLPerson(2)/ModifiedBy</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>ModifiedById</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>OLPersonBUId</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>OLPersonDepartment</key>
<string>Some Text Value</string>
<key>OLPersonEmail</key>
<string>someone@somewhere.com</string>
<key>OLPersonEmployeeID</key>
<string>0000002222</string>
<key>OLPersonFirstname</key>
<string>Some Firstname</string>
<key>OLPersonOfficeId</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>OLPersonSurname</key>
<string>Some Surname</string>
<key>Owshiddenversion</key>
<integer>4</integer>
<key>Path</key>
<string>/mysite/Lists/OLPerson</string>
<key>Version</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>__metadata</key>
<dict>
    <key>etag</key>
    <string>W/"4"</string>
    <key>type</key>
    <string>Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.OLPersonItem</string>
    <key>uri</key>
    <string>http://myserver/mysite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/OLPerson(2)</string>
</dict>
</dict>
```

And the following entity in my core data model you can see that I am returning more fields in my json data that I have in my core data model.  I am only interested in putting the matching fields in the json into the corresponding fields in the model into core data.  e.g. OLPersonBUId value should go into olpersonbu in core data.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface OLPerson : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * olcreatedat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * olpersonbuid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * olpersondepartment;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * olpersonemail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * olpersonemployeeid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * olpersonfirstname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * olpersonoffice;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * olpersonphoto;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * olpersonsurname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * olsyncstatus;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * olupdatedat;

@end
```

I have an issue where the integer values will not go into my core data model because it is expecting a string value.  The correct data types are defined in core data but do not always get back the correct data types in the JSON.

I have the following code:

```
- (void)newManagedObjectWithClassName:(NSString *)className forRecord:(NSDictionary *)record {
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:className inManagedObjectContext:[[OLCoreDataController sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext]];
[record enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [self setValue:obj forKey:key forManagedObject:newManagedObject];
}];
[record setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:OLObjectSynced] forKey:@"olsyncstatus"];
}
```

but it fails because the type it is expecting is not what it is getting from the JSON data.

How can I check the data type of values in the data above and put that data into Core Data while only putting in matching key values and making sure the data going into the values is of the correct data type?

[EDIT]

Adding the below code to explain the issue further.  The problem I have now is that I cannot get the attributes NSDictionary populated with attributes:

```
- (void)newManagedObjectWithClassName:(NSString *)className forRecord:(NSDictionary *)record {
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:className inManagedObjectContext:[[OLCoreDataController sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext]];

NSDictionary *attributes = [[????????] attributesByName];
    for (NSString *attribute in record) {
        id key = nil;
        id value = [key objectForKey:attribute];
        if (value == nil) {
            // Don't attempt to set nil, or you'll overwite values in self that aren't present in keyedValues
            continue;
        }
        NSAttributeType attributeType = [[record objectForKey:attribute] attributeType];
        if ((attributeType == NSStringAttributeType) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])) {
            value = [value stringValue];
        } else if (((attributeType == NSInteger16AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSInteger32AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSInteger64AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSBooleanAttributeType)) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
            value = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[value  integerValue]];
        } else if ((attributeType == NSFloatAttributeType) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
            value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[value doubleValue]];
        }
        [self setValue:value forKey:attribute forManagedObject:newManagedObject];
    }
```

}

I am passing in the className so there is no core data object initialised that allows me to access the attributes.

Comment: You can try using MagicalRecord, it supports importing data. You can achieve this without entering a single line of code for importing. There are some conventions to be followed. If you Entity name is Person, then MagicalRecord expects a personID attribute which will be unique etc. More read http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/

Answer (score 1):

You have to go through the dictionary manually attribute by attribute. That is the only safe way to conduct this import.

```
newObject.olpersondepartment = [record objectForKey:@"OLPersonDepartment"];
newObject.olpersonemail      = [record objectForKey:@"OLPersonEmail"];
// etc.
```

Comment: There has to be a less ugly way of doing this import than going through each attribute individually?

Comment: How does that help if the objects returned by objectForKey are the wrong type for the corresponding object attribute?

Comment: @TomHarrington I was attempting to use your example category on NSManagedObject code from here ( http://www.cimgf.com/2011/06/02/saving-json-to-core-data/ ) earlier to solve my problem above but I can't quite figure it out for my scenario. It will work for me but I'm stuck on how to integrate it with my above code.

Comment: That code would replace your call to 'enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock'. It only works when the JSON keys and the object attribute names match exactly.

Comment: @Mundi I don't think it's possible that the entities on a server (or in my case returned from a SharePoint web service that I have no control over) can always match the objects in core data.  In my case, for example, the listdata.svc returns keys where the first letter is always uppercase even if I change the field name in SharePoint.  But Apple prevent me from setting an uppercase field name in my object in core data.

Comment: @TomHarrington I'll try that.

Thank you both for your help.  I may need more though. :)

Comment: If necessary, it would be easy to add a JSON key name-to-object attribute name translation dictionary to that code.

Comment: What's the correct way to handle this type of scenario in xcode when I have no control over what the web service returns so that the app keeps working if fields are added removed on the server data model?

Comment: You cannot reliably store stuff from a web service that is not consistent. You should have a custom implementation for each field and ignore fields that are unknown. If you really need to store unvalidated stuff, just store the string, even if it might not very usable.